# How can I update the mini-cart without refreshing the page?

Tags: magento-1.9

After I have programmatically added an item to the cart, without reloading the cart page is possible to update the mini-cart, and, if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Yes possible.

You ***`can update mini-cart`*** ,**without reloading the cart page** .

**Assume** that you have using **magento RWD mini-cart**.
In default magento, `minicart_content` block give mini-cart section content,so you **need get that block content using ajax**for your requirement

Let create a controller and render the content from an action.

```
<?php

class [CompnayName]_[ModuleName]_CustomController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
  public function ajaxcontentAction()
    {

        $result = array();

            try {
                $cart =Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
            $this->loadLayout();
                $result['content'] = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('minicart_content')->toHtml();
                $result['qty'] = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getSummaryQty();
                $result['success'] = 1;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $result['success'] = 0;
                $result['error'] = $this->__('some error');
            }

        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this working before loading cart page ?its not working for me.My module is some customization.After adding to cart(in product details page) it should update in mini cart also any load or refreshing the cart page.